# Change a ?= string in the URL to a hashtag

Tags: jquery

I'm looking for a snippet to match ?= in the URL and replace it with a #.

e.g:

http://www.example.com?=100

would become:

http://www.example.com#100

EDIT:- Thanks for the help, was looking to replace ?= with # and used:-

```
  var getURL = window.location.href
  var changeURL = getURL.replace("?=", "#");
  window.location.replace(changeURL);
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: [jQuery is really great and does all things](http://www.doxdesk.com/img/updates/20091116-so-large.gif)

Comment: Is that URL in a string, or the current URL?

Comment: Window location has a lot of built in functionality, look specifically at .hash and .search
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Why do you need to use jQuery?

```
"http://www.example.com?=100".replace("?=", "#")
//result: http://www.example.com#100
```